# Liquid Template Map Filter

Tags: ruby, templates, github, liquid, jekyll

How, exactly does one use the map filter in Liquid? I'm using it in Jekyll.

```
---
my_array: [apple, banana, orage]
my_map:
  hello: world
  foo: bar
my_string: "how does this work?"
---
{{ page.my_map | map ... }}
```

That's about where I get lost. I cannot seem to find any example of its usage in the docs or anywhere else online for that matter.

By the way, I do not know Ruby, yet, so the [source code](https://github.com/tobi/liquid/blob/master/lib/liquid/standardfilters.rb#L81) is not clear to me, either.

From the [filter tests](https://github.com/tobi/liquid/blob/master/test/lib/liquid/standard_filter_test.rb#L75) it looks like the following should produce something, but on GitHub, I am getting nothing:

```
{{ site.posts | map: 'title' | array_to_sentence_string }}
```

I would expect that I should get something like:

```
My First Blog Post, Yet Another Post, and Third Posts
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I was able to do what you want this way:

```
{{ site.posts | map: 'to_liquid' | map: 'title' | array_to_sentence_string }}
```

Explanation:

I think that `site.posts` is returning an array of [Post](https://github.com/mojombo/jekyll/blob/master/lib/jekyll/post.rb) instances instead of returning their `to_liquid` version (which feels very weird - probably it is a bug, you should report it). Instances of that class don't `respond_to? :title`, and since the Liquid code checks for that, the `map` returns nil for all instances.