# Getting an array of all the pages in a Jekyll site

Tags: jekyll, liquid

I can't seem to create an array with all the page titles in my Jekyll site. This is how I'm going about looping through the pages in liquid:

```
{% for page in site.pages %}
{% assign page_title_array = {{ page_title_array | append: page.title }} %}
{% endfor %}

{{ page_title_array }}
```

For example, I have the following page titles in my site: `Alfa`, `Bravo`, `Charlie`, `Delta`. If I run through the loop, the value in `page_title_array` is `Bravo` instead of all the page titles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`map` filter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12303149/368697) for this case:

```
{% assign page_title_array = {{ site.pages | map: 'title' }} %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an empty array :

```
{% assign page_title_array = "" | split: "" %}
```

Then loop in your pages :

```
{% for page in site.pages %}
  {% assign page_title_array | push: page.title %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeeeeeah...I tried the other two answers here because I had the same issue. However, I stepped back, thought about it, and came up with this!

```
{% for page in site.pages %}
  {{ page.title }}
{% endfor %}
```

*Wonderful* for auto-navigation!