# Listing all the key-value properites in site.pages

Tags: jekyll, liquid

On my blog, I have a debug page which lists several things, including all the properties for each page in `site.pages`, like so:

```html
{%- for page in site.pages -%}
    <strong>{{ page.path }}:</strong><br>
    <table>
        {% for key_value in page %}
            {% if key_value[0] == "content" %}
                <tr><td>content</td><td>[{{ key_value[1] | size }} characters]</td></tr>
            {% else %}
                <tr><td>{{ key_value[0] }}</td><td><span>{{ key_value[1] }}</span></td></tr>
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
    </table>
{%- endfor -%}
```

This produces output like this:

[image: example output]

So far, so good.

Now, I want to do the exact same thing with `site.posts`, but it doesn't work.

In particular, `key_value[0]` and `key_value[1]` don't have any value. The iteration does produce *something*, but it is not a key an value.

For example, the following produces a list of key names:

```
{%- for pp in site.posts -%}
    <strong>{{ pp.path }}:</strong><br>
    {% for kv in pp %}
        {% capture cap %}{{ kv }}{% endcapture %}
        <div>{{ cap }}</div>
    {% endfor %}
    <br>    
{%- endfor -%}
```

like so:

[image: example 2]

I can't seem to get the content of the properties in a generic way, however. I guess the *type* of the things in the `site.posts` is not the same as `sites.pages`, in particular not a simple liquid dictionary.

I've tried messing around with `to_liquid` [mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5751830/liquid-template-map-filter) without luck.

Comment: How is that related to Shopify?

Comment: @Vladimir - because liquid is part of shopify? I can remove it if you think it would be clearer that way.

Comment: yes, you're right - liquid is pat of Shopify. Despite that both Shopify and Jekyll use liquid as a template language they are a bit different in terms of objects and filters they do provide. So, I'm as a Shopify dev cannot actually answer your question as it seems more related to Jekyll rather than to Shopify. In Shopify, you don't have such entities like `site`, `site.pages` and `site.posts`.

Comment: @Vladimir - agreed, I removed the shopify tag.